# Citation of a reference with author name in LaTex class spieman?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am preparing my document using documentclass "spieman". The bibliography style of SPIE cites references as a number in superscript. However, I want to cite the reference with the name of the author and year. \citet or \citep are not supported by LaTex class "spieman". Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The `spieman` class loads the `cite` package, which is for numeric citations only. However, you can load the `natbib` package afterwards and use author-year citations as you would do with other classes/documents that load `natbib`, i.e., using the `\citet` and `\citep` commands that `natbib` provides.

Note that if you plan to submit a paper to a SPIE journal then you are not allowed to change the bibliography style, and it will be changed back if your paper is accepted for publication.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{spieman}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet{testarta}

\citep{testartb}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{articles}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]